EspNow recieving not working while using script for camera multiclient webserver
My Problem is that as soon as my esp32 cam starts to stream no msg arrives anymore through EspNow.
However I have a good feeling this script might cause this.
Link
In general I merged this script with EspNow (added my EspNow stuff).
My guess is this scripts puts the esp32 somewhere in some kind of deepsleep, while no client is connected, however i have no clue how to fix this. I have to admit in general I barely even understand this script.
Code
EDIT: I manged to fix it, for anyone with the same problem. Recieving doesnt work because callbacks in general doesnt work at all for the reason the streaming handle stuff runs on core one and by default events(recieve callback fucnction) as well. However you can switch it to core 0: Tools->EventsRunOn->0

Electronics SE might be a better choice to post your question.
